# Access Terminal from OSX 10.4 install disk to replace corrupted libSystem.dylib

Tags: mac, terminal, libraries, ppc

Ive corrupted the libsystem.b.dylib on my PPC mac running 10.4 and i have the install disk.
i know its corrupt because i was the one who corrupted it (long story stinging from GCC errors...)

anyway i would like to replace this file with a backup i made in /usr/lib/libSystem.b.old and all i really need to fix the system is a simple command.

i had a look around on the install disk but was unable to find anything actually useful like a terminal prompt and as it is HFS+ i dont think linux can help me much either.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There's no Utilities->Terminal?

Comment: from the install disk i have a choice of disk utility, new install and the system profile and a few other useless programs for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can restore a single file by booting from the install disk. You can try to connect your Mac to another one in [target disk mode](http://guides.macrumors.com/Target_Disk_Mode); you will be able to access the drive as it was a mounted volume.